# How to authenticate with Azure Cloud using gitlab pipeline to provision infra with gitlab managed terraform state

Tags: azure, gitlab, terraform

I want to provision infra on azure through gitlab pipeline with terraform using gitlab managed terraform state file. Had tried but pipeline failed in plan stage.

This is my pipeline code below. (had forgot to post that please forgive )

```
workflow:
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event"
        when: never
      - when: always

variables:
  TF_DIR: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/terraform
  STATE_NAME: "az_tf_state"
  ADDRESS: "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/${STATE_NAME}"

stages:
  - validate
  - plan

image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint: [""]

before_script:
  - terraform --version
  - export GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN=$TOKEN
  - cd ${TF_DIR}
  - terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="address=${ADDRESS}" -backend-config="lock_address=${ADDRESS}/lock"    -backend-config="unlock_address=${ADDRESS}/lock" -backend-config="username=yashhirulkar701" -backend-config="password=$GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN" -backend-config="lock_method=POST" -backend-config="unlock_method=DELETE" -backend-config="retry_wait_min=5"

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    paths:
    - ${TF_DIR}/.terraform
    policy: pull-push

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan 
  dependencies:
    - validate
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    paths:
     - ${TF_DIR}/.terraform
    policy: pull
```

and getting this error below in PLAN stage on executing the pipeline

```
Error: building AzureRM Client: please ensure you have installed 
Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from 
the Azure CLI: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not 
found in $PATH.

with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
on provider.tf line 11, in provider "azurerm":
11: provider "azurerm" {
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01

ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Is there some code?

Comment: sorry had forgot to post . Have done now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally, I got the solution..!

The solution steps for this is as below:-

1. Create Azure Service principle and client secret in Azure Portal (Link: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_certificate)
2. Copy the Subscription ID, Client ID, Tenant ID and Secret Value for the Service principle
3. Create an IAM role of azure subscription and assign it to Service Principle account.
4. Try to Authenticate using this Service Principle in Azure Cli using command "az login --service-principal -u CLIENT_ID -p CLIENT_SECRET --tenant TENANT_ID"
5. Once Authentication is successful then follow the below step.
6. Create variables in Gitlab for Subscription ID, Client ID, Tenant ID and Secret Value AS ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID, ARM_CLIENT_ID, ARM_TENANT_ID, ARM_CLIENT_SECRET respectively.
7. Then run the pipline as given above. Gitlab will fetch these values with prefix "ARM_" automatically and Gitlab managed terraform state file will be created in Gitlab. Hence, pipeline will succeed.
8. In this way we can authenticate with Azure using gitlab pipeline and create resources on Azure using gitlab managed terraform state.